# deleting the 7 days older files in a folder using the timestamp in the file name in python

Tags: python-3.x

i have the daily uploading of my files which are in the formate `allproduct_bbc_20190409.csv`,`allproduct_bbc_20190112.csv`,`allproduct_bbc_20190514.csv` the number of the files is getting bigger and i wanted to delete the files which are older than 7 days using the timestamp in the filename..how can i solve this??

```py
path = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test"
days_to_subtract = 7
d = dt.today().strftime('%Y%m%d') - timedelta(days=7).strftime('%Y%m%d') 
print (d)
lines = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
 date_filename = dt.strptime(filename.split(" ")[0].filename.split('_')[2],**strong text**'%Y%m%d') 
  if date_filename < dt.dt.now()-dt.timedelta(days=days_to_subtract):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r') as f:
    lines.extend(f.readlines())
```

i expect the output to be like as below in the folder by deleting all the files which are older than 7 days

`allproduct_bbc_20190514.csv`

Comment: you want the file deleted from the hard disk if its old, right?

Comment: ya.i have a list of files from last month in a folder i just need to delete the files which are older than 1 week..using the time stamp in the file name using python scripting

Comment: `os.remove()` can be used to delete files from disk. I will write an answer after a couple of minutes.

Comment: ya os.remove can delete it but i want to use the timestamp in the file name and delete the files..

Comment: i have a doubt can it be done dynamically like i have seven different folders and i have to delete the 7 days older files at a time from all the folders?? can u help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code provided below can be used to delete files from a directory by checking the date in filename.

The first method(`get_date_from_filename`) returns a date object from the filename passed to it, if the filename is in proper format.

The second method(`should_delete`) takes to arguments -> `file_date` and `days`.
If the `file_date` is older than `days` from today then it will return `True` otherwise `False`.

The third method `delete_old_files` deletes the files while making use of the first two methods to perform checks. It takes two arguments `path` and `days`. Path should be a path to a directory inside which the method will check all files and delete them if they are `days` or more older than today. I have passed a default for both these arguments according to your question, but you can change the default according to your need or pass something else in the last line where this method is called.

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
import os


def get_date_from_filename(filename):
    """Retrieve a date object from filename of format xyz_yyyymmdd.xyz."""
    date_string = filename
    # Get rid of file extension
    try:
        date_string = filename.split('.')[-2]
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueError('Oops, looks like an invalid filename!')
    # Take out date part from filename
    date_string = date_string[-8:]
    if len(date_string) != 8:
        raise ValueError('Oops, looks like an invalid filename!')
    # Get year as integer
    try:
        year = int(date_string[:4])
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Invalid year in filename!')
    # Get month as integer
    try:
        month = int(date_string[4:6])
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Invalid month in filename!')
    # Get date as integer
    try:
        day = int(date_string[6:])
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Invalid date in filename!')
    # Convert to date object and return it
    return date(year, month, day)


def should_delete(file_date, days):
    """Check if the given file_date is given days or more older than today."""
    today = date.today()
    return file_date < today - timedelta(days=days)


def delete_old_files(path, days=7):
    """Delete old files in a given directory."""
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        raise NotADirectoryError('Given path is not a directory!')
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        try:
            delete_file = should_delete(get_date_from_filename(filename), days)
        except ValueError:
            print(f'Skipping {filename}')
            continue
        if delete_file:
            print(f'Deleting {filename}')
            try:
                os.remove(os.path.join(path, filename))
            except:
                print(f'Unexpetced error while deleting {filename}!')
        else:
            print(f'Skipping {filename}')

# pass days too if required
delete_old_files(path="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test")
delete_old_files(path="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\another_folder")
delete_old_files(path="D:\\Yet\\Another\\Folder")
```

Comment: i have a doubt can it be done dynamically like i have seven different folders and i have to delete the 7 days older files at a time from all the folders?? can u help me with that?

Comment: You can pass `path` to the function `delete_old_files`. I have updated my answer, see the definition of function `delete_old_files` and the when it's called(at the bottom).

Comment: I have not tested it but it should work. If there is some error, copy paste it here.